# Binding a Large List in Windows Phone ListPicker control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application, i am using the Windows Phone toolkit ListPicker control to allow users to select some option.

When i try binding the control with a list having around 3000 records, i keep getting System.AccessViolationException . I tried the same with around 1000 records but the performance was really poor.

I have seen some applications displaying such large list with almost no performance bottleneck.

What is the best way to display such large list in Windows Phone application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use LongListSelector to display a list of items.

A really good approach in case of a lot of items is to display them in chunks. Do you need all 3000 items at once? Probably not. Load a 50-100 and then load more either when user clicks somewhere, or when he scrolls to the bottom of the list. That way you will get better performance and the user will have the same experience just like in many other Windows Phone apps.

If for some reason you really mean ListPicker, then I would reconsider that because, from user's perspective, I would never want to pick from a list of 3000 items.

Comment: Will give LongListSelector a try. I want to give the user an option to scroll through the list or have a search box inside the template which can fetch the data based on search criteria

Comment: Is there any way the long list selector can be used like a dropdown list, where the user can click and it displays a list of item like in List picker.

Answer (score 1):

ListPicker is designed to manipulate only on a few items. For large data sets try to use [LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)